# How to direct certain hosts in the host_group to different var files?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have two hosts- 198.51.100.2 and 198.51.100.3, both configured under the same group in /ansible/hosts file. Now I want these two hosts to use two different var files that is, 100.2 to use main_R1.yaml and another router other var file. Is it possible?

My file structure-

```
automation@automation:~/lab8/ANSIBLE/RTR-TEMPLATE$ tree
.
├── ospf.yaml
└── roles
    └── router
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yaml
        ├── templates
        │   └── router.j2
        └── vars
            └── main_R1.yaml  
            └── main_R2.yaml
```

Comment: As written this is not possible. All variables in the vars and defaults directories will get included into the role scope. What you might do is instead is use some combination of default values, the ternary jinja2 filter, conditional tasks, or inventory host or group variables, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to conditionally *include_vars*. (Only vars/main.yml is loaded automatically.)

Import tasks/vars.yml as a first task in tasks/main.yml

```
- import_tasks: vars.yml
```

and create tasks/vars.yml

```
- include_vars: main_R1.yaml
  when: ansible_hostname == "198.51.100.2"
- include_vars: main_R2.yaml
  when: ansible_hostname == "198.51.100.3"
```

More flexible option would be to map such hosts and files

```
my_host_vars:
  - {host: "198.51.100.2", vars: "main_R2.yaml"}
  - {host: "198.51.100.3", vars: "main_R3.yaml"}
```

and *include_vars* in a loop in task/vars.yml

```
- include_vars: "{{ item.vars }}"
  loop: "{{ my_host_vars }}"
  when: item.host == ansible_hostname
```

If you can rename and move the var files "The preferred practice in Ansible is" [Splitting Out Host and Group Specific Data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data). It is necessary to understand rather complex [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Comment: And where do I configure these parameters?                                           
 `my_host_vars:
  - {host: "198.51.100.2", vars: "main_R2.yaml"}
  - {host: "198.51.100.3", vars: "main_R3.yaml"}`

Comment: In vars/main.yml